# Timeout issue when running background PHP script as web

Tags: php, linux, shell, nearlyfreespeech

I've got a PHP script that does some heavy lifting that I'm trying to fire off as a background script using the following code:

`exec("script.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &");`

What happens:

- When I run the code above as part of my web app, the script quits
  after about a minute.
- When I run the code as part of my web app without the final
  ampersand, the job runs fine - but `exec()` waits for the script to
  complete before loading the next page, defeating the purpose as the user stares at an unresponsive page.
- When I run the shell command `script.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &` as myself from the console with the final ampersand, the job runs fine.
- When I run the shell command from the console as web, the job stops running after about a minute.

I've tried piping my output to logfiles: `script.php > /home/public/tmp/output.txt 2> /home/public/tmp/errors.txt &`. Output looks normal, I don't get any errors. The script just stops working.

The basic rule seems to be: If run as a foreground process as web or as me, it'll complete. If run as a background process as web, it stops working after about a minute.

I'm not running this as a cronjob because my host (NearlyFreeSpeech) can only run cronjobs once an hour, which is more than I want to make users wait for when the job only takes a couple minutes- it might as well fire when users initiate it.

The subscript starts with `set_time_limit(60 * 60 * 4);` so this shouldn't be a matter of PHP timing out.

Comment: try piping your output to a log file to see if an error or anything unexpected occurs `script.php > /tmp/script.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: Tried that. It just stops unceremoniously.

Comment: 60 seconds does sound suspiciously like a timeout issue... try dumping `phpinfo()` into your output log to ensure `max_execution_time` is being updated by your `set_time_limit()` call? (hosting companies can restrict what you can set to prevent adverse effects to other users)

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit
```

does not include shell-execution time.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Try using of the code examples in the comments on that site.

Comment: Not true, I just tested it myself; `set_time_limit(1)`  gets me `Fatal Error Error: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded`.